# How to save an image from Google

Tags: php, javascript

I am new in programing. I want to save images from Google Images. I can use filter for only the free ones. I use a Google API, I have the URL and I want to pass it to PHP, but I don't know how to pass it from JavaScript to PHP. I try it with forms, and `document.write('<a href="prueba4.php?url1=unescapedUrl">save the image</a>');` but it doesn't work.

```
function MyKeepHandler(result) {
    // clone the result html node
    var node = result.html.cloneNode(true);
    // attach it
    var savedResults = document.getElementById("content");
    savedResults.appendChild(node);
    // extract some info from the result to show to get at the individual attributes.
    // see http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/reference.html
    var title = result.title;
    var unformattedtitle = result.titleNoFormatting;
    var content = result.content;
    var unescapedUrl = result.unescapedUrl;

    document.write('<a href="prueba4.php?url1=unescapedUrl">save the image</a>');
    // alert("Saving " + unformattedtitle + " " + unescapedUrl + " " + content);
    var_dump($x);
}

function OnLoad() {
    // Create a search control
    var searchControl = new google.search.SearchControl();
    // Add in a WebSearch
    var webSearch = new google.search.WebSearch();
    // Add in a full set of searchers
    searchControl.addSearcher(new google.search.ImageSearch());
    //var localSearch = new google.search.LocalSearch();
    // tell the searcher to draw itself and tell it where to attach
    searchControl.draw(document.getElementById("content"));
    searchControl.setOnKeepCallback(this, MyKeepHandler);
    // execute an inital search
    searchControl.execute("tomates");
}

google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);
</script>

</head>
<body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
<div id="content">Loading...</div>
</body>
</html>
```

For saving an image I was using this (this works if I use URL-name):

```
function saveImage($url,$path) {
    $c = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
    curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    $s = curl_exec($c);
    curl_close($c);
    $f = fopen($path, 'wb');
    $z = fwrite($f,$s);
    if ($z != false) return true;
    return false;
}
saveImage($url1,$path);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I noticed:

```
document.write('<a href="prueba4.php?url1=unescapedUrl">save the image</a>');
```

There is no variable interpolation in JavaScript so this will output the exact text. Change it to:

```
document.write('<a href="prueba4.php?url1=' + unescapedUrl + '">save the image</a>');
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, you were right, but I cannot pass the url name to php. It says that doesnt exist url1 variable. "Notice: Undefined variable: url1 in C:\server\www\imagenes\prueba4.php on line 16"

Comment: Change `$url1` to `$_GET['url1']`

Comment: Martin Dimitrov THANKS SO MUCH!!! Finally it works!!! I am so happy. You are the best, today my prayers are for you ;)